# installed redis but can't see it in nmap's scan

Tags: centos, redis

Redis installed and looks to be running:

```
[me@hsredistest01 ~]$ sudo systemctl status redis
● redis.service - Redis persistent key-value database
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/redis.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/redis.service.d
           └─limit.conf
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-04-22 19:03:35 +03; 34min ago
 Main PID: 8780 (redis-server)
   CGroup: /system.slice/redis.service
           └─8780 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
```

It says running port 6379 here, but when I scan the running service ports I can't see it.

```
[me@hsredistest01 ~]$ sudo nmap -sT -O localhost

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2019-04-22 19:40 +03
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000078s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
25/tcp  open  smtp
111/tcp open  rpcbind
199/tcp open  smux
Device type: general purpose
Running: Linux 3.X
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3
OS details: Linux 3.7 - 3.9
Network Distance: 0 hops

OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.73 seconds
```

I just want to type 192.168.0.23:6370 in browser and see something like `Redis is fine` message.

Comment: Redis is configured to listen on localhost by default because of security reasons. You could need to alter redis conf in /etc first and restaet the service

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy hello yes you are right, can you check this link as well about that topic please; https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/513908/why-connection-refused-by-hostcentos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not run a `nmap` scan that would reach port 6379, [the default is to only scan 1000 of the most common open ports](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-specification.html).

You can pass a single port to nmap: `nmap -p 6379 -sT -O localhost`

or you can pass a range of ports: `nmap -p 1-65535 -sT -O localhost`

The more ports scanned, the longer it will take.

Also, make sure your firewall allows connections to the port or `nmap` will not see it.

Comment: While it is correct about nmap, redis config is also something to consider. See my comment under question