# why connection refused by host(centos)

Tags: centos, redis

There is redis service running on centos 7.6 it looks fine there,(192.168.0.24:6379)

I try to connect this client from another machine in same network(192.168.0.22)

There is incoming request from that client in tcpdump interfaces look fine

but nothing in monitor of redis service.. so its obvious something block connection which make me suspect on firewall of course..

I did exactly what [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-secure-redis-centos-7) article says.. no problem occurred during installation, But still I get message like;

> "No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it 192.168.0.24:6379"

Not: redis is running on port 6379

Comment: Is `redis` actually listening on that IP address, or is it listening on `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` or some local socket?  According to the instructions you referenced, `/etc/redis.conf` would have the line `bind 127.0.0.1` which would make it not accessible to any machine but the one where `redis` is installed.  You should follow those instructions to use your own private IP, such as `bind 192.168.0.24`.

Comment: [Redis is configured to listen on localhost by default because of security reasons. You could need to alter redis conf in /etc first and restart the service](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/513853/installed-redis-but-cant-see-it-in-nmaps-scan#comment950243_513853)

Comment: @GracefulRestart I am on it

Comment: @GracefulRestart gratefulRestart :) I happily accept your answer since I solved it thanks!